# Verify a function with argument it called with mockito

Tags: flutter, testing, mockito

I have a test suit that checks if fireService method was called (addModelToCollection) when the currentUser has a uid. When verify is called on the method, it throws an exception saying the on method called is this

FirestoreServiceMock.addModelToCollection('businesses', Instance of 'Business', {id: uid})

```
      test('fireStore service should be called', () async {
    // Arange
    final authService = getAuthServiceMock();
    final fireService = getFirestoreServiceMock();
    when(authService.currentUser).thenReturn(UserModel(uid: 'uid'));
    when(fireService.addModelToCollection())
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value('sdfff'));
    final model = RegistraionViewModel();
     
    model.createBusiness({
      'title': "text",
      'description': "text",
    });
    
    verify(fireService.addModelToCollection('businesses', business, id: 'some string'));
  });
```

error

```
No matching calls. All calls: FirestoreServiceMock.addModelToCollection('businesses', Instance 
of 'Business', {id: uid})
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
package:test_api                                             fail
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 670:7                          _VerifyCall._checkWith
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 986:18                         _makeVerify.<fn>
test\viewModel_test\registration_view_model_test.dart 60:15  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
```

Imnew to mockito and testing and I'm not sure what is going here, any help ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is the `business` that you have entered in your verify method? My best guess based on only the code you provided above would be that the object `business` and the one used in the real method are not the exact same (hash different). And the `id` being `uid` instead of `'Some String'` is because of the `when(authService.currentUser).thenReturn(UserModel(uid: 'uid'))`

For further clarification/explanation please provide the `.createBusiness()` method